# React handleChange syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I've got a handleChange function in my React code and I'm just wondering about the syntax.

```
handleChange: function(event){

    var newState = {};            
        newState[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
},
```

My question is, if `var newState` is an empty object, and `event.target.id` looks like it's being put into an array (`[ ]`) next to the empty object, what happens when you put an object next to an array? Am I even reading this correctly?

Comment: how does the initial state look like in your app?

Comment: You are not putting it into array. only an entry is being created for the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I even reading this correctly?

No. This is standard [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) access for objects.

If `event.target.id` is "a", then the object will look like: `{a: event.target.value}`.

Comment: Thank you! I never use bracket notation and I guess I just didn't realize what it was!

Answer (score 2):

The `someobject[...]` syntax is [property accessor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) - it's equivalent to using `someobject.someproperty`, except the name of the property which will be accessed is the value of the expression inside the square brackets.

For example, if the value of `event.target.id` is `'name'` for a particular call, then your `handleChange()` method will do the equivalent of `this.setState({name: event.target.value})`.

Comment: This makes sense now! Thank you! I guess I just haven't ever really used bracket notation before!

Answer (score 1):

So in the above code

`newState` is an empty object and `newState[event.target.id]` is way to access the obejct parameter, so if we do

```
handleChange: function(event){

    var newState = {};            
        newState[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
},
```

we are assiging the value `event.target.value` to the object attribute which is `event.target.id` if it doesn't already exist. So suppose if `event.target.id` is `"name"` and `event.target.value` is `"Mike"`. the newState will become

```
newState = {
    name: "Mike"
}
```

Comment: I understand it now! Thank you! I've only ever really used dot notation before so I didn't realize what it was. Thanks!